# Change data.table column values dynamically inside a function?

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

How do you change the values in a data.table column within a function?

```
DF = data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18)

change_it <- function(data_table) {
    data_table[[column]] <- 73
}

column = 'a'

change_it(DF, column) # Nothing happens because data_table is not a reference (or something)

DF[[column]] <- 73 # The change happens
```

Comment: @Waldi Reading that question I'd argue it is about adding rows. Perhaps you meant a different one?

Comment: Do you want to modify a `data.table` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, a data.table

Comment: Might this about local and global assignment? `<<-` within a function will assign to the object as defined outside the function. Otherwise it's just a local assignment that is dumped when the function ends (or returned as a return value)

Answer (score 2):

It works with the := operator like so:

```
DF = data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18)

change_it <- function(data_table) {
    data_table[, c('a') := 73]
}

change_it(DF) # The change occured
```

This would change the values in-place.

Comment: Is there a good writeup on the wulrus operator? I've never seen it used outside dplyr assignments

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/jesse-smith/covidsms/man/tidyeval-walrus.html from this I'm still not clear why it does a by ref assignment

Comment: @pluke It's actually a `data.table` feature, try `?data.table::\`:=\`()`.

Comment: By its own documentation, definition, and intent, `data.table` does as much as possible *by-reference*. It will make copies of data (aka "the normal R way to do things" aka "copy on write") when you subset rows, subset columns, or manually (not `data.table`-canonically) reorder the rows. (Or explicitly `copy(.)` it, of course.) (And TIL it's called a walrus ... makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem:

```
change_it <- function(data_table) {
  set(data_table, j="a", value=73)
}

# apply the change
change_it(DF)
```